# I'm hitting a roadblock when trying to install Cython

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to install Cython, which I need for using another package. I have Xcode and a C compiler. I'm using a Mac (Big Sur) with python 3.9, but I have no experience with C.

I first tried using pip:

```
pip3 install Cython
```

This resulted in the message

```
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.29.23)
```

and I was unable to import the package into my editor, Idle. Usually, every package I install goes to

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

so I tried downloading the zip file from https://github.com/cython/cython and placing it in the above site-packages directory. At the terminal, I changed to the directory cython-master and entered

```
python3 setup.py install
```

which seemed to work since a number of messages popped up on my screen, none indicating errors, and the whole thing ending with

```
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/Cython-3.0a7-py3.9-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for Cython==3.0a7
Finished processing dependencies for Cython==3.0a7
```

However, I'm still receiving a module not found error a my shell in Idle.

Comment: Maybe it's because you tried to import a different module that you haven't installed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The module I eventually want to use is called pyedflib. It requires Cython, but I haven't tried to download or install pedflib yet since the documentation states I will need Cython. It's Cython that I can't import.

Comment: I don't know, you didn't show which import failed.

Comment: >>> import Cython

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>

     import Cython

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

Answer (score 0):

Typically happens with a wrong pip executable.

1. Use `$ python -mpip install`
2. Use virtualenverapper (or the standard library venv module)